# How to get the matching element of a set in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a Python program involving a graph over a number of states represented by immutable objects.  The process of generating the graph produces many duplicate copies of each state.  There are a large number of states, so to save memory I would like to keep just one copy of each state in the final graph object.  Therefore, I would like to build a set of canonical states, and write a function like this:

```
def canonicalize(state, canonical_states):
    if state in canonical_states:
        state, = (cstate for cstate in canonical_states if cstate == state)
    else:
        canonical_states.add(state)
    return state
```

This function takes a state and returns the "canonical" version of that state.  If the state has not been seen before, it becomes the canonical version.

It should be possible to look up a set element in roughly constant time, but this implementation requires O(n) time for each lookup.  Is there a better way?

One solution is to represent `canonical_states` as a dict mapping elements to themselves (see my answer below).  I'd prefer a solution that achieved this performance without changing the type of `canonical_states`.

**In a nutshell:** Given that `x in S` for some set `S`, is there a way to get the element `y` of `S` such that `x == y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Represent the set of canonical states by a dict mapping each state to itself.  Then the code becomes something like this:

```
def canonicalize(state, canonical_states):
    return canonical_states.setdefault(state, state)
```